# Rails asset pipeline with Backbone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, heroku, asset-pipeline

I am building a Rails app with the frontend in Backbone. Although it is working locally, I am having trouble deploying to Heroku. I keep getting the following error:

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: punc (.) (line: 15308, col: 23, pos: 459589)
remote:        Error
```

I'm finding it very difficult to research/troubleshoot, but I'm guessing that something within my javascripts/application.js might be the problem. Here are the requirements I currently have.

```
//= require 'backbone/app.js'
//= require 'backbone/models/hood.js'
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require underscore
//= require backbone
//= require backbone_rails_sync
//= require backbone_datalink
//= require_tree .
```

Does anyone have any troubleshooting ideas or see something that is wrong?

Comment: did you try updating your gemfile.lock before pushing it to Heroku?

Comment: I just went ahead and tried that, but still didn't have any luck pushing to heroku. Thanks for the thought!

Comment: I'm not sure but the order might matter. Did you try to put `//= require 'backbone/app.js'` stuff after backbone_datalink?

Comment: Good idea, but no luck. Still getting that same error. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Finally solve the issue! I had been using a spread within Math.max (as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Examples) but it was not being recognized.